# Numeric formatting difference between .NET Framework and Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm porting some .NET Framework projects over to .NET Core 6 and there are some unexpected differences in string formatting for negative numbers.

Using the format string `"0.##"`, the numeric value: `-0.004` gets rendered as `"-0"` in .NET Core, whereas in .NET Framework the value gets rendered as simply `"0"`

The following snippet demonstrates the behaviour in .NET Core:

```
System.Console.WriteLine((-0.004).ToString("0.##"));
```

The correct rendering in my opinion should be `"0"`, as was seen in .NET Framework.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get .NET Core to behave in the same way as .NET Framework?

Does anyone know the reason for this change? Oversight, or deliberate change?